# How do I keep persistence authentication in angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in angular js.I am trying to do demo application.In which I have login screen as a first screen.After login other views are loaded.Also I have navigation Bar which is included using ng-include in index.html page.Navigation bar is shown by ng-show="isAuthenticated".

Where isAuthenticated flag is initialised to false in app.js shown as below,

```
app.run([
'$route', '$rootScope', '$location','datacontext',
function ($route, $rootScope,$modal,$modalInsatnce, $location,datacontext) {
    $rootScope.isAuthenticated=false;

}]);
```

isAuthenticated is set to true in login view's control,so navigation bar can be visible.

My problem is that when I refresh any loaded view then it hides navigation bar ie isAuthenticated is set to false in app.js.How can I keep loged in when page is refresh.

Answer (score 0):

most likely toy want to use cookie authentication, when the app start on the server side you need to check if the user is logged in. if you find the authentication token then set the isAuthenticated to true else set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

Simple option which I am using is,

in server side itself update $rootscope when the page loads (or reloads),

// after angular js and your app.js

```
<script>
$rootScope.isAuthenticated = @(User.IsAuthenticated)
</script>
```